# Regarding service instance

Tags: routing, switch, switching

```
interface g0/2
      service instance 1 ethernet
        encapsulation dot1q 18
        rewrite ingres tag pop 1 symmetric
        bridge-domain 44
      service instance 2 ethernet
        encapsulation dot1q 66
        rewrite ingress tag pop 1 symmetric
       bridge-domain 44
    !
    interface Vlan44
      ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
```

What is the above config likely to achieve?

Please explain line by line.

My understanding:

If the vlan 18 tagged traffic comes to this interface,it will be placed in
service instance 1 .

The vlan18 tag will be popped out
Now 'bridge-domain 44' will result in looking at the vlan 44 for the destination mac.
If found ,all OK
else:
 If the destination is out the other Service Instance, the frame will be placed on Service Instance 2 and a new VLAN tag(tag 66) will be added

a.Please validate this understanding

b.Using the above,we are making vlan 18 talk to vlan 66 ? Is that the only objective?

c.How on earth, for 2 different vlan tags(vlan tag 18 and vlan tag 66) be using the same ip address(for routing)

ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

d.I am also remembering traditional dot1q subinterfacing(router on a stick) method.Using that i could do inter-vlan routing?Why do i need such a complex scenario?

e.If we were to connect a L2 switch to this interface g0/2,and say we have a PC one connected to switch on vlan 18, what would be it's gateway?
Similarly , i connect another PC two(vlan 66) to switch,what would be the gateway?
How can i make PC one and PC two talk to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the vlan 18 tagged traffic comes to this interface,it will be
>   placed in service instance 1 .

Correct

> The vlan18 tag will be popped out Now 'bridge-domain 44' will result
>   in looking at the vlan 44 for the destination mac. If found ,all OK
>   else: If the destination is out the other Service Instance, the frame
>   will be placed on Service Instance 2 and a new VLAN tag(tag 66) will
>   be added

Close.   I confess I'm not 100% sure if the tags need to be explicily translated like:

```
rewrite ingress tag translate 1-to-1 dot1q 66 symmetric
```

rather than the way you have it.  I would have to lab it up to be sure.

> a.Please validate this understanding
>
> b.Using the above,we are making vlan 18 talk to vlan 66 ? Is that the
>   only objective?

You also have a layer three interface, 192.168.1.1

> c.How on earth, for 2 different vlan tags(vlan tag 18 and vlan tag 66)
>   be using the same ip address(for routing)
>
> ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0

Since VLANs are layer 2 and IP is layer 3, they operate independently of each other.  VLANs don't know about subnets, and IP doesn't know about VLAN tags.

> d.I am also remembering traditional dot1q subinterfacing(router on a
>   stick) method.Using that i could do inter-vlan routing?Why do i need
>   such a complex scenario?

You are not doing routing.  Even though there are two VLANs, at layer 3 they are the same subnet. If you have devices on different IP subnets on each VLAN, they will not be able to talk to each other.

> e.If we were to connect a L2 switch to this interface g0/2,and say we
>   have a PC one connected to switch on vlan 18, what would be it's
>   gateway? Similarly , i connect another PC two(vlan 66) to switch,what
>   would be the gateway? How can i make PC one and PC two talk to each
>   other?

They would have to be in the same IP subnet, and their gateway would (normally) be 192.168.1.1